# How can I animate the spin function?

Tags: animation

I'm trying to create the rotation of a solid around an axis and I am struggling to figure it out.

Comment: This Blender Guru video should give you a solid and quick answer. http://bit.ly/22g6GJ6

Answer (score 2):

Objects will rotate around their Origin Point. So, one simple way would be to move the objects Origin Point. Move the cursor to your desired axis then in “Object Mode” select the “Set Origin” drop down menu in the tool bar (Press <kbd>T</kbd> to toggle on and off) then select “Origin to 3D cursor”.

Another option would be to add an “Empty” to your desired axis and then parent the object <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to the “Empty” and then rotate the empty.

Answer (score 2):

In edit mode model the profile you want to spin. Then add a screw modifier. You leave the screw setting at 0.0 and animate the angle value.

[image: spinning animation]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate the solid around its own centerline axis (i.e. the earth spin during a day), then you can just keyframe the rotation properties of the object.

If you want to rotate the object around a point outside itself (i.e. the earth travel during a year), I suggest you add an "Empty" (sometimes referred to as "null object" or "origo") and then put your object (the solid) into the Empty (using the outliner, or by using hotkeys as mentioned in other comments).

To insert a keyframe you need to have the window Timeline open. In the bottom line of that window, there is a little red button. Click that red button and set your rotation data for either the Solid or the Empty (or both). Then move to the frame at the end of the animation, and set the end rotation there. 
This should generate the keyframes you need.